# Create a link that calls our custom function in WordPress

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

I want to create the a link like https://mywordpresssite.com/mypage, that should call my function and execute the code. I am doing this for my backend script call that link and send some parameters to save data in database, I want to create that link by plugin only so it will use any of other wordpress websites

I tried this by searching-

```
add_action( 'wp_loaded', function() {
if ( $_SERVER[REQUEST_URI] == '/mypage' ) {
data_collection();
}
});

function data_collection(){
//my coding stuff
}
```

But this showing me error and not worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
add_action( 'wp_loaded','data_collection');

function data_collection(){
   if ( $_SERVER[REQUEST_URI] == '/mypage' ) {
   //my coding stuff
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function data_collection() {
    // My coding stuff
}

add_action('wp_loaded', function () {
    if (basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) == 'mypage') {
        data_collection();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, its works. I have a question - Is any other way to achieve this ?

Comment: function data_collection(){
//my coding stuff
}

function call_custom_function(){
 if ( isset($_GET['query_parameter']) ) {
  data_collection();
 }
}

add_action('wp', 'call_custom_function');

Add above code in theme functions file and hit this URL from browser:

https://mywordpresssite.com/?query_parameter